# Angular Universal displays comments instead of dynamic component data

Tags: angular, firebase, server-side-rendering, universal

**PROBLEM DESCRIPTION**

Angular Universal does not display the dynamic data of my "Posts" component when I click on "View Page Source". Although, what is a little weird, is that I will see it sometimes... I think it's a timing/delay thing. If I load a page and let it sit for 10 mins or so, and then click "View Page Source" again, then I will see the missing dynamic content that was not there before. Doesn't happen consistently every time, though!

**PROBLEM EXAMPLE**

See the comment tags below (i.e.: `<!---->`)? That's where the data/content should be!

```
<div _ngcontent-sc413="" class="post"><!----></div><!----><!----></div></app-post-detail-page><!----></app-root>
```

**ANGULAR VERSIONS**

- "@angular/cdk": "^14.2.3"
- "@nguniversal/express-engine": "^14.2.0"

**WHAT I'VE TRIED**

I set up Angular Universal by following two excellent tutorials:

- This [YouTube tutorial from Codeible](https://youtu.be/k7pLxaKkHYs);
- The ["Angular Universal In Depth (Angular 15)" course from Udemy](https://www.udemy.com/course/angular-universal-course/);
- In terms of trying to fix my problem, I've done a bunch of desperate Googling. Nothing I've tried has worked (although I haven't tried everything yet). It seems the likeliest culprits might be:

  - I might need to use Angular Resolve (See [this stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69795551/angular-ssr-with-universal-and-ionic-doesnt-show-actual-data-in-page-source))
  - I might have to look into TransferHttpCacheModule (See [this stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52270397/angular-6-angular-universal-not-waiting-on-content-api-call))
  - I might have to make sure I set up TransferState (See [this YouTube video](https://youtu.be/juvYWRrLtAg))

    - Sidenote: Not sure if "TransferState" is the answer...we do have "BrowserTransferStateModule" in place ... although VSCode is now yelling at me and telling me this is deprecated; visiting Angular itself explains [that we can now just use TransferState without injecting the BrowserTransferStateModule](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/BrowserTransferStateModule).

So, I haven't really tried anything, so much as researched a bunch of things, without knowing which is the correct path to follow.

What's even more confounding is that some posts/articles state that Angular Universal [does not display dynamic data automatically](https://softtechdiary.com/display-dynamic-content-in-angular-universal/), while others [say that it does](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49300575).

Comment: You've shown the client-side code here, but what does it look like before being rendered on the server side?

Comment: I should have included more code ... but I finally just figured out the issue, and have answered this below. I sure hope it helps anyone else who might be struggling with the same scenario!

Answer (score 0):

I can now finally answer my own question.

The problem was that the server was pointing to the wrong environment, so it wasn't retrieving any information.

You see, we have 2 Firebase environments:

- Staging
- Production

So, STAGING somehow thought its environment was PRODUCTION on the server side. It would try to go to the PRODUCTION database, and use a STAGING id it received from the client to try to get data.

I .... this took forever to figure out!

Everything is now working swimmingly in my STAGING environment, thanks to a tiny update to the **angular.json** file. In the "server" section, the "defaultConfiguration" is set to "production". I simply changed it to "development".

***angular.json file, with "defaultConfiguration" updated to point to development***

```
"server": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/my-project/server",
            "main": "server.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.server.json",
            "optimization": false,
            "sourceMap": true,
            "extractLicenses": false
          },
          "configurations": {
            "test": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.test.ts"
                }
              ]
            },
            "production": {
              "outputHashing": "media",
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractLicenses": true
            },
            "development": {}
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
    },
```

I still need to use either a Resolver or a "waitFor" on the main parts of the data that I need to see in "View Page Source", but it works now, because it's reading from the correct database.

YEESH.

I hope this helps someone out there :)